# Ubuntu only recognizing the SSD that I used for the install

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, raid, disk

all. I'm a very new user to Ubuntu, and I'm trying to get my storage up and running. When I first installed Ubuntu, I already had my RAID array set up, and put the OS on my SSD. I checked Files>Other Locations>Computer, and it shows "129.5/145,6GB Available," so it's currently only using the SSD that the OS was originally installed on.

To clarify, I currently have three HDDs, and an SSD (2x 1TB HDD, 1x 700GB HDD, 1x 150GB SSD). I used my on-board Marvell RAID controller to set up the two 1TB drives in RAID 0 before installing Ubuntu.

Running `lsblk` in the Terminal returns:

`NAME                  MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE   MOUNTPOINT
loop0                   7:0    0   2.3M  1 loop   /snap/gnome-calculator/180
loop1                   7:1    0 140.9M  1 loop   /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/70
loop2                   7:2    0  42.1M  1 loop   /snap/gtk-common-themes/701
loop3                   7:3    0  87.9M  1 loop   /snap/core/5548
loop4                   7:4    0   2.3M  1 loop   /snap/gnome-calculator/238
loop5                   7:5    0  14.5M  1 loop   /snap/gnome-logs/37
loop6                   7:6    0    13M  1 loop   /snap/gnome-characters/103
loop7                   7:7    0   3.7M  1 loop   /snap/gnome-system-monitor/57
loop8                   7:8    0   3.7M  1 loop   /snap/gnome-system-monitor/51
loop9                   7:9    0  14.5M  1 loop   /snap/gnome-logs/43
loop10                  7:10   0  34.7M  1 loop   /snap/gtk-common-themes/319
loop11                  7:11   0    13M  1 loop   /snap/gnome-characters/124
loop12                  7:12   0  86.9M  1 loop   /snap/core/4917
sda                     8:0    0 139.8G  0 disk

└─sda1                  8:1    0 139.8G  0 part

  ├─ubuntu--vg-root   253:1    0 138.8G  0 lvm    /
  └─ubuntu--vg-swap_1 253:2    0   976M  0 lvm    [SWAP]
sdb                     8:16   0 698.7G  0 disk

└─sdb1                  8:17   0 698.7G  0 part

sdg                     8:96   0 931.5G  0 disk

└─ddf1_raid           253:0    0   1.8T  0 dmraid 
sdh                     8:112  0 931.5G  0 disk

└─ddf1_raid           253:0    0   1.8T  0 dmraid 
sr0                    11:0    1  1024M  0 rom`

So it's showing my RAID array there on sdg and sdh, and my 700 GB drive on sdb, but it seems that Ubuntu is simply not using that storage. What I want to have is my RAID 0 array and my 700GB drive available to use. I did some searching online and got pretty lost for what I need to be doing here, as I'm not terribly familiar with terminal commands or really any OS outside of Windows. Do I need to go into the Marvell controller and delete this array before I start doing anything?

Thanks in advance for any help and replies :)

Comment: The only disk you have so far mounted is sda; so your raid-disks will sit unused until you `mount` and give them a place on your system (where files can be read/write to them). You'll get better newbie advice from others (I hope), but you could look at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingANewHardDrive  (documentation). You need to "Create a Mount Point"  (eg. /array/ which means anything saved to that directory goes to your raid-array; you can pick the name; doco uses /media/mynew..) then "Mount the Drive" (I'd use fstab myself, but your choice).  I've used headings from the wiki/doco.

Comment: I've run into a bit of an issue; that link you provided mentions that I need a) "determine the path that your system has assigned to the drive" and b) "partition the disk"

I ran `sudo lshw -C disk` and it shows both members of my array, but does not show the array itself. This confuses me, because when I open GParted, it shows me the array and allows me to partition it. GParted also shows the two members of the array as independent disks which can be partitioned as well. Do I need to mount and partition each member separately? or am I missing something that will allow me to mount the array?

Comment: I literally don't know what I did, but it seems to be working now... I was just trying to mount the 750GB drive and it mounted the RAID array with it. Thanks for the help.